# create a dameon of a script that checks if httpd service is on or off

Tags: linux, bash, email, unix, command

## Script to check if httpd is on or off

```
#!/bin/bash    
service=service_name  
email=user@domain.com     
host=`hostname -f`  
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))  
then  
echo "$service is running"  
else  
/etc/init.d/$service start  
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))  
then  
subject="$service at $host has been started"  
echo "$service at $host wasn't running and has been started" | mail -s   "$subject" $email  
else  
subject="$service at $host is not running"  
echo "$service at $host is stopped and cannot be started!!!" | mail -s   "$subject" $email  
fi  
fi
```

How do I make this script run in background so that it keeps checking if httpd service is on or off and emails a message if it goes off !! ( PS-: I DON'T WANT TO MAKE THE SCRIPT AS A CRONJOB) just like a daemon process which runs in background!!
               Please Help

Comment: What kind of help you want? Write code for you?

Comment: Do you already have this script and the question is "How can I run it in the background?".

Comment: Please check on [how to write a minimal complete verfiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

If you launch the script with nohup it will run as a daemon.

```
nohup script.sh &
```

Comment: No; if you run it with `nohup` it will ignore the `HUP` signal. The `&` runs it in the background. Neither of these, isolated or together, is sufficient to properly daemonize the script.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but that is how we get this kind of checks running on background, as I understood It is being asked.

Comment: It's a start, but it's not a proper daemon just because it runs in the background.  See e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/1/daemonize for things a daemon will commonly want to do.